# Password protect network link on Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, kml, security

I plan on serving data with geoserver to multiple people in my organization. The data is somewhat sensitive and I was wondering if there is a way to password protect the info so that in order to visualize it on Google Earth as a Network link, you would need a global password?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to look int using HTTP Basic authentication in GeoServer (supported by default) specifically for data.
You can activate it for certain layers only, here below some good resources:

1. [Security in GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html)
2. [Layer Security](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/layer.html)

Hope this helps.